# MS-SQL Connect on a Media Temple DV 4.0

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, mediatemple

I'm really stumped on this on.  Trying to connect to a MS-SQL database with php on my mediatemple DV 4.0 server.

I was able to get it working on our DV 3.5 using these instructions

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/233/Using+%28remote%29+MS-SQL+databases+with+PHP+on+a+%28dv%29

But the same steps dont work on the 4.0.

I even tried installing FreeTDS and reinstalling the 64 bit version:
freetds-devel-0.64-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

and then i changed

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = v0.63 with protocol v8.0
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0  - changed to /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
```

after i did that it go rid of all the errors I was seeing but I am still seeing

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source, SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/vhosts/housingworks.org/httpdocs/p/dbtest.php on line 9
```

this is where i am running the test: http://www.housingworks.org/p/dbtest.php

HELP!

Comment: could it be as simple for you to solve as it was for this person? http://thebigbyte.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-connect-to-mssql-odbc-from-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on why you are getting these errors, as you should be able to use that (mt) Wiki to connect to MySQL throughout all of our services. Try giving us a call regarding this connection error, and one of our higher level techs may be able to get things sorted out for you. (877) 578-4000.

Comment: When i put in a ticket and support said they couldnt help me?!?  I really need to be able to connect to MS Sql server otherwise we will have to cancel our hosting and find a host where it will work